# Put multiple elements in single area in CSS grid

Tags: css

I am using a CSS grid. To get an idea of the layout, please look at the CSS:

```css
.grid {
    position: relative;
    left: 135px;
    top: 158px;
    width: 1080px;
    height: 1015px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 79px 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 60px;
    grid-column-gap: 60px;
    grid-template-areas: "headings headings headings"
                         "a b c"
                         "d e f";
}

#headings-section {
    grid-area: headings;
}

.a {
    grid-area: a;
}

.b {
    grid-area: b;
}

.c {
    grid-area: c;
}

.d {
    grid-area: d;
}

.e {
    grid-area: e;
}

.f {
    grid-area: f;
}

.temp {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Here's the html:

```html
<div class="grid">
    <section id="headings-section">
        <h1 id="welcome-heading">Welcome to Icon Utopia!</h1>
        <h3 id="introduction-heading">Everything about <a href="free-icon-design-guide.html">iconography</a> and <a href="build-your-dribbble-audience.html">building your career</a> as a designer.</h3>
        <p>Wondering where to start?</p>
    </section>
    <div class="temp a"></div>
    <div class="temp b"></div>
    <div class="temp c"></div>
    <div class="temp d"></div>
    <div class="temp e"></div>
    <div class="temp f"></div>
</div>
```

Here's the problem I am running into: I have set `grid-row-gap: 60px` but this is the result that I get:

[image]

[image]

The two headings and the paragraph in `id="headings-section"` are where I want them to be, but the gap between the paragraph and the next grid row is 40px instead of 60px. I think that all three of the elements are not fitting into the first grid row. Later, I plan to add four elements inside each of the `div`s. I am wondering, maybe I made the wrong choice by using the grid. Is there a way to add multiple elements into the same grid area? And apparently setting the `grid-area` for the entire section doesn't do what I intend. Should I instead use another method for laying out the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the height to your headings section as `79px`. The content of your heading section exceeds this height and is overflowing into your grid gap. I'd suggest setting the height to `auto` instead:

```css
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 1fr;
```

You might need to remove the `margin-bottom` from the last element in your headings section to get the gap to be a perfect `60px`.

I think you made the right choice by using grid. Your blocky layout and need for row/column gaps suits it well. To have more than one element in a grid area I recommend setting the `grid-area` for a parent element, then giving the parent multiple child elements as you wish.

Comment: Thank you. I realized the mistake that I was making: I had set `padding-bottom: 10px` for both the headings and I wasn't taking it into account when calculating the height of the grid, and of the first row. I also thought it was irrelevant, so I didn't add that information in the question. My mistake.